# How to force an implementing class to inherit from one or another subclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have an abstract class `MotherClass` and two abstract classes `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` that extend `MotherClass`.

I wish to make sure that any class extending `MotherClass` will in fact extend `ChildClass1` or `ChildClass2`. I feel that something is wrong in my tree-based class design. Do you see how to make it properly?

Comment: Can `MotherClass` be private?

Comment: Why do you want to force this?

Comment: @Mark Because my `MotherClass` is not "typed" enough for use ; instances derived from that class need to implement some more functionality, either through `ChildClass1` or `ChildClass2`.

Comment: I understand that, but how is that different from any abstract class?   What is so insidious about somebody extending `MotherClass`, as long as it satisfies the substitutability principle?  Why are you trying to protect yourself from other developers? This is ass-backwards: you're supposed to expose the generic types and hide the implementation classes.

Comment: @Mark agreed, It is a bit messy. Thank you for your answers ! I won't implement them but I learnt things - the whole purpose of the site in the end, it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `MotherClass` has package visibility and `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` are public and in the same package, you could subclass those two but not MotherClass.

Edit:

Another possibility:

```
interface Marker {} //note that this is package private

public abstract class Mother<T extends Marker > {}

public class ChildA extends Mother<ChildA> implements Marker {}

public class ChildB extends Mother<ChildB> implements Marker {}
```

Method:

```
doSomething(Mother<?> mother() {}
```

You now couldn't do

```
class GrandChild extends Mother<GrandChild> {}
```

This would compile but give you a warning at least:

```
class GrandChild extends Mother {} //warning like "Mother is a raw type"
```

Ways without warning:

```
class GrandChild extends ChildA {} 
class GrandChild extends ChildB {}
```

Comment: 5 seconds ago got this idea =) (+1)

Comment: I still need to make their common root visible. Not all functionalities are specific to the Child subclasses, so I need to be able to pass one or the other class as a `MotherClass` in some methods.

Comment: Then employ a common interface which is used for the parameters and is implemented by `MotherClass`. Other than that, you'd need to check for `instanceof` like Joachim Sauer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the constructor of `MotherClass`:

```
protected MotherClass() {
  if (!(this instanceof ChildClass1 || this instanceof ChildClass2)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Oh noes!");
  }
}
```

This (admittedly ugly) solution was inspired by SWT which has code like this in it's `Widget` class:

```
protected void checkSubclass () {
    if (!isValidSubclass ()) error (SWT.ERROR_INVALID_SUBCLASS);
}
```

`checkSubclass` is called in the only constructor of `Widget`.

This is done to avoid subclassing SWT widget classes (because that's unsupported and should not be done). Note that `checkSubsclass()` is **not** `final`. So if you **really** wanted to extend `Button` (and were prepared to live with the consequences) you could overwrite `checkSubclass()` as a no-op method.

Comment: and tomorrow he will get ChildClass3 and ChildClass4 and forget to modify the constructor...

Comment: Thanks :) But this will give an error at runtime, not at compile time. I want to ensure this weird behavior at compilation.

Comment: @Mark: agreed, but that's already in the requirement, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to convince him that his requirements are broken too :-).

Answer (score 1):

Extract common functionality from `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` and move it to `MotherClass` or some other abstract class derived from `MotherClass`.

Comment: the point is that if you want to enforce inheritence of two classes, then they have something in common and it can be moved upper. If no, then you do not need such restrictions.

Comment: You didn't get me right. I want that a class extends one or the other of the subclasses - not both of them !